# R Function -- Calculate Age Groups + Null Age

Tags: r, grouping, categorization

Trying to make categorize age group, but there may be Null ages. Wanted to have the groups "0-4", "5-24", "25-49", "50-64" "Over 64" AND "Null Age".

I am a novice with R; trying to alter someone else's codes.

### Calculate Age Groups

Here is the original code:

```
calculateAgeGroup<-function(this.age,this.age_units) {

  if(is.na(this.age) || is.na(this.age_units) || this.age=="NA") { return(NA) }

  # first of all, if age has a comma, take lower number
  this.minAge<-min(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(this.age,","))))

  # calculate div factor for date unit
  this.divFactor = 1
  if (grepl("^y",this.age_units,ignore.case=TRUE,perl=TRUE)) { this.divFactor = 1 }
  if (grepl("^m",this.age_units,ignore.case=TRUE,perl=TRUE)) { this.divFactor = 12 }
  if (grepl("^d",this.age_units,ignore.case=TRUE,perl=TRUE)) { this.divFactor = 365 }

  this.yearsOfAge = this.minAge/this.divFactor

  # now calculate age group Age 0-4,5-24,25-49,50-64,over 64
  if (this.yearsOfAge < 5) { return("0-4") }
  if (this.yearsOfAge < 25) { return("5-24") }
  if (this.yearsOfAge < 50) { return ("25-49") }
  if (this.yearsOfAge < 65) { return ("50-64") }
  return("over 64")

 }
```

When it's run, I receive the following error(s):

> Error in if (this.yearsOfAge < 5) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In mysqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :
>     RS-DBI driver warning: (unrecognized MySQL field type 7 in column 1 imported as character)
>
> 2: In function (this.age, this.age_units)  : NAs introduced by coercion

Answer (score 3):

May be this helps

```
AgeGrp <- as.character(cut(v1, breaks=c(0,4,24,49,64,Inf),
          labels=c('0-4', '5-24', '25-49', '50-64', 'Over 64')))
AgeGrp[is.na(AgeGrp)] <- 'Null Age'

AgeGrp
```

#### data

```
set.seed(39)
v1 <- sample(0:90, 40,replace=TRUE)
v1[5] <- NA
```